# removing menu block title causing problems

Tags: routes, blocks

I know how to remove the menu title from the block by going into the block setting and putting

```
<none>
```

in the title space.

But when i do this a smaller version of my menu appears in place of where the title was.

any clues on how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has now been solved. Problem was the omega framework setting can be forced to render a menu, as well as being able to publish a menu via blocks. If both are enabled you will see two menus, so you have choose which part of drupal you want to render the menu, blocks or the omega framework I chose blocks :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try to put in the block title

```
<none>
```

instead of space

Comment: sorry i think system filtered out my tag

to clarify i have put the 

    <none>

tag in this is when it appears

Comment: Do you have any custom `block.tpl.php` template files in your theme?

Comment: Nope fresh install of the latest drupal

Comment: which theme do you use? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Im developing a theme on the Omega HTML5 framework

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/screenshot20120511at125.png/

Its now not even taking note of the 

    <none> tag and displaying it all the time